# How to draw an image in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I would like to draw in pure Latex the three following images:

[image: to draw]

Could you suggest me a package to do it (or directly how to do)? Thanks, Vi.

Comment: You can use `Tikz` package.